# Rails # within HTML href comments out the line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, escaping, encode

In my controller I am setting a variable equal to an HTML string in order to account for a base case. However, `#` comments out the rest of the line. How can I escape this?

```
@chart_data = "<p id='chart-notice'>If you <a href="#SOME_ID">login to your social media apps</a>, this section will display social analytics.</p>"
```

Note: this is not an `.html.erb` file it is `.rb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@chart_data = <<-HTML.strip!
  <p id='chart-notice'>If you <a href="#SOME_ID">login to your social media apps</a>, this section will display social analytics.</p>
HTML
```

Or

```
@chart_data = %Q{
  <p id='chart-notice'>If you <a href="#SOME_ID">login to your social media apps</a>, this section will display social analytics.</p>
}.strip!
```

Or

```
@chart_data = "<p id='chart-notice'>If you <a href=\"#SOME_ID\">login to your social media apps</a>, this section will display social analytics.</p>"
```

Pay attention to the `\`

Comment: If you're using both types of quotes, `%Q` is the least messy solution. `<<` is the HEREDOC style which is great for multi-line strings as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
@chart_data = "<p id='chart-notice'>If you <a href='#SOME_ID'>login to your social media apps</a>, this section will display social analytics.</p>"
```